# Calling a servlet from result tag in struts2

Tags: struts2, migration

Migrating from struts1 to struts2.5. In struts-config forwarding request to the servlet.wondering how we can achieve in struts 2

Comment: https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/dispatcher-result

Comment: Tried this in location given servlet name but did not work.

Comment: Define “did not work”. Dispatcher result is how to do this.

Comment: In struts 1 application in the forward tag my one action is calling a servlet now I am trying to convert the same in struts 2 using the type = dispatcher in result tag and in location passing the servlet name . Getting error no action found for namespace /

Comment: Ok. We can’t magically diagnose a problem with absolutely no context.

Comment: Here is the snippet of code:

Comment: Additional information should be added to the question.

Comment: <action name =“create” class =“com.ChooseCreare” method=“execute”> <result name =“call” type=“dispatcher”><param name=“location”>/Package/</param></result>

Comment: Package is my servlet class

Comment: Please edit the question to include the additional information.